# Checking whether the user authenticated using spring security inside a filter

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-plugin

I'm trying to do this in my groovy class which is in `src` directory of my grails application.

Its an `Filter`. The class looks like this :

```
class Proxy implements Filter {
}
```

Inside the `init` method I'm getting the `springSecurityService` bean using :

```
GrailsApplication application = org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ApplicationHolder.getApplication()
springSecurityService = application.getMainContext().getBean("springSecurityService")
```

And inside my `doFilter` I'm trying to find whether the user is been authenticated or not. I tried:

```
springSecurityService.isLoggedIn()
```

but its always returning `false`.

Where I'm making the mistake?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Were you trying to create a Grails filter? If so there is a command to do so, and that will wire up everything for you

Comment: Its not an grails filter. Its an class inside `src` directory. And I configured `web.xml` to intercept the requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible the order of your filters are incorrect? Your custom Filter would need to be invoked after the Spring Security Filter. If you perform `new Exception().printStackTrace()` inside your filter, do you see the `SecurityContextPersistenceFilter` in the stack? If not, then you need to change your Filter (Proxy) to be after the springSecurityFilterChain.

Comment: oh you mean in the `web.xml` file?

Comment: If you are using a web.xml with Grails, then yes this is one way to control the ordering. Remember it will invoke in the order you specify the filter-mappings elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use SecurityContextHolder

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()
```

(but this is Java; I'm sure there is something similar you can find)